# Объявлено ли свойство в классе?

Tags: php

```
class MyClass{  
public $var0;  
private $var1;  
protected $var2;  
  function __construct(){  
    for($i=0; $i<4; $i++){  
      $varname = 'var'.$i;  
      if(объявлена($this->$varname)){  
        print($varname.' here');  
      }else{  
        print('there is no '.$varname);  
      }  
    }  
  }  
}
```

Вывод:

```
var0 here    
var1 here  
var2 here  
there is no var3
```

Реализуемо? Как?
P.S. isset не сработал "почему-то".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А если попробовать функции:

```
print_r(get_class_vars("MyClass"));
print_r(get_class_methods("MyClass"));
```

Которые возвращают в массивах все и к тому же возвращают начальные значения.
И, как я понимаю, не зря вы в классе используете модификаторы `private`, `public` и `protected`. Так вот данные функции как раз работают правильно с модификаторами.

Comment: Отл, вполне сойдет. Далее - можно уже пробежаться по этому массиву. Спасибо.